# Is it possible to create attributes out of the class scope?

Tags: python, oop

Is it possible to add attributes to a object outside of its scope?

I.e: The following code doesnt works, how do I do what I intended to do with that code?

```
b = object()
b.foo = "bar"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, it is possible. However, it is not possible for most types that are implemented in C, instead of in Python. Unfortunately, this applies to the most often-used of the standard Python interpreter's built-in types.

If you define a class of your own in Python, you'll see that it works fine.

```
class MyObject(object):
    pass

b = MyObject()
b.foo = "bar"
```

Comment: The solution for all built-in types, if you really need custom attributes, is to do what you did for `object` -- create an empty subclass.

Answer (score 5):

Instances of `object()` are "[featureless](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#object)" by design in that they do not have any magic methods (no dict, no getters/setters, no iteration, etc.) to dictate default behaviors you might expect from other types. In order for it to work you must subclass `object` first:

```
class Foo(object): pass
f = Foo()
f.bar = "omgwtf!"
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with mutability. Try `list().foo = 'bar'`.

Comment: An instance of `object()` is literally featureless (no dict, no getters/setters, no iteration, etc.). An instance of `list()` has *some* features (`__len__`, `__iter__`, `__contains__`, `__getitem__` to name a few), but getting/setting attributes is not one of them.

Comment: The point was that it isn't mutability or lack thereof that prevents adding attributes to instances of built-in types, which is what your answer implies.